# Need to access storage bucket of project B in project A through a data flow job in google cloud (data flow job failing)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-iam

I am running a data flow job in project A where I have a requirement of accessing storage bucket in project B.  I have requested the admin to add the service accounts of project A in project B and have given the required permission
As you can see below, I have provided the screen shot of project B whose storage bucket I need to access in project A and run data flow in project A and load BIG QUERY table in project B.

Project A service account (as highlighted by A) as shown is added in project B and given big query admin and storage admin role.

Data flow runner service account is also added as you can see but looks like admin provided big query admin and storage admin role there and not compute network user. Not sure if I need to add data flow runner service account of A in B but I am getting below error while running the data flow job.

It mainly says "-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.objects.list access to the Google Cloud Storage bucket.",\n "domain": "global",\n "reason": "forbidden"\n }\n ]\n }\n}\n>')}')}"

I have tried to provide project name as A AND B in the screen shot below for better understanding. Was not sure of any better way to explain.

Do I need to add .compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com of A in project B too??
Please advise.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run a dataflow job, you have workers. If you have a closer look to your project, worker are simple Compute Engine. And when you deploy compute engine, by default, the service account used is -compute@ . Thus it's this identity which try to access to your different component (GCS and BigQuery here).

So, grant the required permission on the correct resources (don't do this at project level, it's better to do this at bucket or dataset level. If you don't know how to do, let me know).

The other solution is to specify a custom service account at runtime in your Dataflow job to create workers, not with the Compute Engine default service account, but with the provided one. You can do this with the [gcloud CLI for example](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/dataflow/jobs/run#--service-account-email)

---

About Dataflow permission, you can find more details [here](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/concepts/security-and-permissions)

Comment: hello @guillaume blaquiere. Thanks much for looking into my query. I understand what you are saying but please correct me if my understanding is wrong. Do I need to add <A>-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com from project A in project B and

Comment: and give it owner access?? 
the way I added service account of project A in project B and gave required access, similarly shall I do for compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com ? 
I tried doing as mentioned in google documentation https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/concepts/gcs-buckets using "gsutil defacl ch -u \" command but looks like this works for ACL and not IAM. 
  It will be great if you could tell me how to do this right and as you said to do this at bucket and dataset level and not at project level.

Comment: adding comments separately as it didn't allow me to write more in one go.

Comment: The Owner permission doens't have Cloud Storage persmission if you use uniform IAM policy on your bucket. And owner isn't a good idea. You need to add BigQuery admin and StorageAdmin to your <A>-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com in the IAM page of project B. A better solution is to do this resource by resource, but start like this, you will reduce the permission later.